# Dynamics Ax 7 SOAP-based Custom Service logs

Tags: axapta, aif, dynamics-ax7

In AX 2012 the AIF document service can maintain log exception/history. Now in AX 7 AIF don't exist anymore. Is there any way (out of the box) to maintain logs for SOAP-based custom services or we have to do it manually.

Comment: Well, maybe discontinued really means *discontinued*. Anyway you may get something here: https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/dynamics-ax-7-services-technical-concepts-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Surely, AIF is discontinued but SOAP based services are still supported in AX along with new JSON based services.

And logs for custom services can be found under windows default event viewer,
use the path as:
Event viewer> Microsoft > Dynamics > AX-WebApiXppServices > Operational

I am not sure about any out of box solution to maintain logs.